# Socket.io issue with multiple Kubernetes pods

Tags: nginx, socket.io

We have our application deployed in Kubernetes with Nginx+
When we use just a single replica (pod) the socket.io client establishes connection and receives data.

But when we add multiple pods with load balancing the socket.io client tries to connect and then disconnects quickly with xhr error.

```
[2020-01-16T19:10:50.031Z] ERROR: local server/17108 on TEST: Connection error
Error: xhr poll error
at XHR.Transport.onError (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Projects\broker-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transport.js:67:13)
at Request. (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Projects\broker-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:130:10)
at Request.Emitter.emit (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Projects\broker-client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
at Request.onError (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Projects\broker-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:311:8)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Projects\broker-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:258:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by adding `transports: ['websocket']` to socketIOClient options in our multi-pod Kubernetes environment:

```
socketIOClient(someUrl, {transports: ['websocket']});
```

Link to same issue in socketio's github Issues: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3539